# How can I debug X11 missing mouse ButtonRelease events that are present in usbmon?

Tags: x11, mouse, debugging, events

A few days ago, my mouse button releases began sometimes not being recognised when I release two of the buttons simultaneously. The logical state of one button therefore gets stuck on "down", causing annoying unintended actions until I press it again to reset it.

I **could** reproduce the issue monitoring mouse events in `xev` (output sometimes doesn't show expected key release events). I **could not** reproduce the issue by monitoring events in `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon` (output is always consistent with reality).

So the fault clearly lies with a software component at some abstraction below X11, but above USB.

What could be causing this? How could I narrow this down further?

Comment: For reference, I've [reported this upstream on the libinput bug tracker here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103673). I originally noticed this way downstream while playing *Dota 2*, on which bugtracker I filed [this report](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Dota-2/issues/1342) before self-closing it when I realised the problem is deeper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The levels between USB events and X events are:

- Unless your mouse is special and has its own driver, it's very likely a HID device. Find the corresponding `hidraw` device (check `dmesg`), and verify you get events there. USB to HID translation is done by the kernel.
- All input events leave the kernel through the input-layer, the corresponding devices are in `/dev/input`. Run `evtest` as root, select your mouse, see if you get events. Translation from HID events to input events is done by the kernel.
- X automatically loads drivers for all input devices, in most cases the `evdev` driver. See `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` about which driver(s) get loaded. These drivers translate input events to X events.

Comment: i think `libinput` is replacing `evdev` in X these days.

Comment: @quixotic: `libinput` is for Wayland what `evdev` is for X. So unless you are using an X emulation under Wayland instead of "real" X, you are using `evdev`.

Comment: there's a wrapper driver for Xorg as well.  on Arch this is provided by the `xf86-input-libinput` package.  see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput and https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-xf86-input-libinput

Comment: the stack diagrams at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev point out the distinction between `evdev` the kernel driver and `xf86-input-evdev` the Xorg driver: `kernel > libevdev > xf86-input-evdev > Xserver > Xclient` vs `kernel > libevdev > libinput > xf86-input-libinput > Xserver > Xclient`.  as you point out, which driver is loaded and used should show up in the Xorg logfile.

Comment: @quixotic @dirkt Thank you both for your knowledge! Results: My `evtest` output looks correct even when the issue occurs, so the kernel and libevdev must be innocent. I don't have xf86-input-evdev installed, so the correct route up must be through libinput → xf86-input-libinput → X11. The logging tool for libinput is apparently `libinput debug-events`, where the problem finally *appears* in the logs! That narrows it down to libinput. I'll contact the developers.

Comment: So the obvious (at least temporary) thing to try is to deinstall `xf86-input-libinput`, and install `xf86-input-evdev` instead, and see if that fixes the problem.